# using JNA for sched_setaffinity

Tags: java, linux, pthreads, jna

using as a reference I was writing some code to manually set the thread priority for a thread(for learning purposes). I'm using the following code :-

```
final IntByReference cpuset = new IntByReference(1);
final int ret = lib.sched_setaffinity(0,(16),cpuset);
System.out.println(ret);
```

Im compiling the Java code as follows :-

```
javac -classpath jna-4.0.0.jar JNATestOne.java
```

and I get the following error :-

```
JNATestOne.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
          final int ret = lib.sched_setaffinity( 0, cpuMaskSize, new LongByReference( mask ) );
                             ^
  symbol:   method sched_setaffinity(int,int,LongByReference)
  location: variable lib of type CLibrary
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In one case you're using IntByReference (pointer to 32-bit) and the other you're using LongByReference (pointer to 64-bit).